# Java Derby Database and XML Transactions

Tags: java, xml, database, derby

I am programming an MVC application using Servlets. I have an RDBMS wherein there are two tables: Author and Book. The 2 have a many-to-many relationship. The requirement I have is to implement 2 data stores: an Apache Derby database and an XML file. My question is how do I handle correct transactional behavior? For example, suppose I update a Book and modify its set of Authors, but Books are stored in an XML file and Authors are stored in an RDBMS. How do I ensure the individual datasets only update if both persistent stores succeed? 
Thank you.

Comment: You could store your XML in Derby. Derby has an XML data type which allows you to store and retrieve XML data from a Derby database.

Answer (score 0):

To use RDBMS transaction capability you must use XML Database or XML files as blob in a RDBMS, and as long as you have it your requirements can be satisfied.

Having XML in OS file system, you will need to build your custom transaction manager to handle transaction between OS files system and RDBMS.